# how to merge two classifier xml genrated by haartraining in opencv

Tags: xml, opencv, haar-classifier

I have been trying to find a way to merge training files (.XML) generated by the haartraining.exe program.  The haartraining program will output an .XML file; my question is… Is it possible to merge two different .XML files into one .XML file with all of the training data in it?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think OpenCV will support this, nor the others, as merging them will probably destroy one of them or both.

Instead of doing this, you can easily merge their results together in your program.

Comment: hello, can you please tell me what you meant by this?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan What I meant is to merge the detection results, e.g. face rects for face detection.